# UITableView does not respond normally when I scroll during loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have come across a very tedious problem. When I try to load data asynchronously and then finally call -reloadData the tableview does not decelerate upon a scroll event and does not respond to touch events. How can I prevent this from happening ?

Comment: Are you sure the data is being loaded asynchronously?  If the UI is not responding, then either something is being done on the main thread or you're running low on memory.

Comment: @iWasRobbed yes, i am sure. the UI responds normally and the table view scrolls, but the cells do not respond to touches and it does not decelerate anymore when the data is fully loaded.

Comment: Is the table loaded with data and behaving normally before your asynchronously data load? Can you post the code for your load?

Comment: @sangony it behaves normally when I don't drag while It is loading. Now I assume while it is loading it may cause some lags during the dragging or something but not that it totally disables the table view. Well the code is quite extensive and it is very late now , maybe I will post some code tomorrow.

Comment: No problem. I am kinda agreeing with iWasRobbed. Perhaps your call is not asynchronously, I would NSLog a message upon load completion for your reference to see table performance during load and after load. I also assuming you are using a block to load your data.

Comment: @sangony what annoys me really is that the table view is not working properly. I have googled this problem and nobody seems to have run into this problem in the past which really puzzles me...

Comment: I feel you. These things can be really frustrating. What data format are you using: XML, JSON? I can post up some sample code for you if you want. Maybe this will give you a push in finding your issue.

Comment: @sangony: turns out the problem was actually that I loaded data on the main thread somewhere (as I said, code is quite extensive). Thank you for your assistance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a table view with some data in it. The user is manipulating the table as new data comes in asynchronously. The proper way to modify the table is to not use reload data, but to use the "insert..." methods, which leave existing cells alone.